# Calendar iframe shows up to right of textbox the first time and then under it from then on

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, detailsview

**Environment:**
ASP.NET Web Forms
DetailsView control
Edit mode

I have a `date input field` that shows my `iframe calendar` when you click inside the text box. This is all inside a `detailsview edit template element`.

First time it show calendar to right of text box (desired result), but from then on if I hide then show it again, it appears below the text box. Why the inconsistency? Any ideas?

```
$('.update-date-started').on('click',
    function () {
        var $tdElement = $(this);

        var $cal = $tdElement.find('#calFrame');

        if ($cal.length == 0) {
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.src = 'CalendarPopup.aspx?field=tbDateStarted';
            iframe.id = "calFrame"
            iframe.width = '275'
            iframe.height = '203'
            iframe.style = "position: absolute;"
            $tdElement.append(iframe);
        }

        $cal.toggle();
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just had to create a `span`, add the `iframe` to that, and then add the `span` to the `td` element, works now!